# Bivariate normal distribution hazard rate

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal with
$\mu=\begin{pmatrix}
0  \\
0
 \end{pmatrix}$,  $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2 & \rho \sigma^2  \\
\rho \sigma^2  & \sigma^2
 \end{pmatrix} $

Is it possible to show that for some $\sigma>0,0<\rho<1$, it holds for every $y\in \mathbb R$,

$$x- E(Y|Y\leq y, X=x)$$

is nondecreasing in $x$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$?

I   write the formula as

$$x-\rho x+ \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sigma \frac{\phi(\frac{y-\rho x}{  \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sigma})}{\Phi(\frac{y-\rho x}{  \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sigma})}$$

where $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are cdf  and density of the standard normal distribution. Is there any way to further simply the formula?

Thanks.

Comment: For every $(\rho,x,y)$, let $A_{\rho,y}(x)=x-E(Y\mid Y\leqslant y,X=x)$, then some function $A_{\rho,y}$ is nondecreasing if and only if every function $A_{\rho,y}$ is for every real $y$. This happens if and only if $$\frac{1-\rho}{\rho}\geqslant\sup_{z\in\mathbb R}\frac{\varphi(z)}{\Phi(z)}\left(z+\frac{\varphi(z)}{\Phi(z)}\right),$$ where $\varphi$ and $\Phi$ are the standard normal PDF and CDF.

Comment: And the supremum seems to occur when $z\to-\infty$ and to equal $1$. Thus the monotonicity result would hold for every $\rho\leqslant\frac12$ but not otherwise.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I didn't see how the inequality is derived. Could you help me about it? But if I directly take the derivative wrt to $x$,  then I have $ (1-\rho)+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sigma    F'(\frac{y-\rho x}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sigma  })   (\frac{-\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sigma }) \geq 0$, where $F(z)=\frac{\phi(z)}{\Phi(z)}$. I notice that $F(z)$ is decreasing in $z$. Thus, for all $0\leq \rho<1$, we have the monotonicity? Also, $z+F(z)$ is an increasing function in $z$?

Comment: Indeed the supremum in my answer is $\sup(-F')$ and your condition reads $1-\rho-\rho F'\geqslant0$, which would translate into $(1-\rho)/\rho\geqslant\sup F'$ instead of "my" $(1-\rho)/\rho\geqslant\sup(-F')$. My guess is that there is a sign error in your computations and this guess is supported by the fact that the property does not hold when $\rho=1$ (but I will not be able to look at the matter in the next moments).

Comment: When$ \rho=1$, it seems that the property holds since we have $x-E(Y|Y\leq y,X=x)$ is $x$ if $y<x$ and 0 if $y\geq x$.

Comment: Thus, not nondecreasing if $y<0$.